# Java 8 lambda null check usage

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I have a scenario where I am checking multiple attributes inside a class for null check.If its not null , I am calling a method which will create me a new object and I need to capture this instance against a reference.I am succesasfully able to do null check using maps but unable to write code which will help me in capturing the return object after invocation.Can someone please help ?

```
    private WorkflowPreference buildWfPrefDetails(CcarReportPreferenceConfig ccarReportPreferenceConfig) {
    WorkflowPreference workflowPreference = new WorkflowPreference();
    List<PayloadEntry> payLoadEntries = new ArrayList<PayloadEntry>();
    Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getRwpRole)
        .map(RwpRole::getRoleName)
        .ifPresent(s -> workflowPreference.setKey(s));
    Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSequenceNumber)
        .ifPresent(s -> buildPayLoadEntry("SEQ_NUM", s));
    Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSlaType)
        .ifPresent(s -> buildPayLoadEntry("SLA_TYPE", s));
    Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSlaValue)
        .ifPresent(s -> buildPayLoadEntry("SLA_VALUE", s.toString()));
    Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getRejectSequence)
        .ifPresent(s -> buildPayLoadEntry("REJECT_SEQUENCE", s));
    Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getRaiseQueryNotification)
        .ifPresent(s -> buildPayLoadEntry("RAISE_QUERY_NOTIFICATION", s));
    workflowPreference.getValue().addAll(payLoadEntries);
    return workflowPreference;
}

private PayloadEntry buildPayLoadEntry(String key, String value) {
    PayloadEntry payloadEntry = new PayloadEntry();
    payloadEntry.setKey(key);
    payloadEntry.setValue(value);
    return payloadEntry;
}
```

Expected Now :

payloadEntries list should capture the returned object after each buildPayloadEntry call.I want something like below to be implemented along with lambda null checks

```
payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("SEQ_NUM", ccarReportPreferenceConfig.getSequenceNumber()));
payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("SLA_TYPE", ccarReportPreferenceConfig.getSlaValue().toString()));
```

Updated Answer as per below suggestions

```
Optional.ofNullable(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getRwpRole)
        .map(RwpRole::getRoleName)
        .ifPresent(s -> workflowPreference.setKey(s));
    Optional.ofNullable(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSequenceNumber)
        .ifPresent(s -> payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("SEQ_NUM", s)));
    Optional.ofNullable(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSlaType)
        .ifPresent(s -> payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("SLA_TYPE", s)));
    Optional.ofNullable(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSlaValue)
        .ifPresent(s -> payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("SLA_VALUE", s.toString())));
    Optional.ofNullable(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getRejectSequence)
        .ifPresent(s -> payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("REJECT_SEQUENCE", s)));
    Optional.ofNullable(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getRaiseQueryNotification)
        .ifPresent(s -> payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("RAISE_QUERY_NOTIFICATION", s)));
    workflowPreference.getValue().addAll(payLoadEntries);
```

Comment: Apparently, you already know about the existence of the `map` operation. So it’s unclear, why you use `ifPresent` instead. But the big question is *what* do you expect to be potentially `null`?

Comment: Look at `Objects.requireNonNull(ref)`, which evaluates to the ref if the ref is non-null, and throws if it is.  It was intended to facilitate precondition checking.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just need to transform (for example):

```
Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSequenceNumber)
        .ifPresent(s -> buildPayLoadEntry("SEQ_NUM", s));
```

to

```
Optional.of(ccarReportPreferenceConfig)
        .map(CcarReportPreferenceConfig::getSequenceNumber)
        .ifPresent(s -> payLoadEntries.add(buildPayLoadEntry("SEQ_NUM", s)));
```

Comment: Prefer `Optional.ofNullable` to `Optional.of`. The latter assumes its argument to be non-null, whereas the former translates a null to `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: @Jubobs no. If ccarReportPreferenceConfig is not supposed to be null, I want the code to fail fast by throwing an NPE signalling the mistake, rather than returning incorrect results silently.

Comment: @JBNizet In this case if it returns without processing its fine.I do not want anything to happen if my object is null

Comment: @Jubobs is this what you expect and is this correct ?.Please refer to the updated question

Comment: @JBNizet Good point. It all depends whether a null reference is acceptable or not, I suppose.